# how to force UTF8 into a link A with data content?

Tags: javascript, html, utf-8, icalendar, charset

with a 100% client side, i wish to provide a text file (ics calendar by example) to my user.

i managed to process the entire code but the download file is in ISO and i wish it was in utf8 (because ical/ics charset must be utf8).

what did i miss to force the utf8 ? i put the META and the charset but the downloaded file remains  in ISO charset, i don't understand why.

here my little sample to test , you can copy/paste into a new textfile to run it:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
<div><a id="mylinkICS" download='my_own_agenda' class='mylinkICS'> [ CLICK HERE TO DOWLOAD your agenda ]</a></div>
</body>

<script>
var mybigstring="BEGIN:VEVENT\nUID:me@google.com\nDTSTAMP:20120315T170000Z\nATTENDEE;CN=My Self ;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:me@gmail.com\nORGANIZER;CN=Me:MAILTO::me@gmail.com
\nDTSTART:9:30am\nDTEND:10:30am\nSUMMARY:étudiant accentué \nEND:VEVENT";

var icsMSG="BEGIN:VCALENDAR\nVERSION:2.0\nX-WR-CALNAME:EDT test\nNAME:Emploi du temps test\nPRODID:ENT-test\nCALSCALE:GREGORIAN\nMETHOD:PUBLISH\nX-WR-TIMEZONE:Europe/Paris\nX-WR-CALDESC:description agenda\n";

icsMSG=icsMSG + mybigstring;
icsMSG=icsMSG + "END:VCALENDAR";
icsMSG="data:text/calendar;charset=utf8," + escape(icsMSG);
//jquery version $(".mylinkICS").attr("href", icsMSG);
document.getElementById("mylinkICS").href=icsMSG;  //dom version
</script>

</html>
```

in my content (stored in mybigstring var), i add accented word  "étudiant accentué" . so when you download the file, you can see the accents are not showned in utf8  because the file is ISO.....  i don't understand why....

Comment: "_you can copy/paste into a new textfile to run it_" is the culprit: you also have to save/serve your file as UTF-8. Just advertizing it everywhere as such does not mean it is saved as such magically. Verify that in your text editor. If you have an URL for others to download from then add it to your question.

Answer (score 1):

since time passed, i found the answer :
escape() function  send iso charset  so i used encodeURIComponent

i replaced

```
icsMSG="data:text/calendar;charset=utf8," + escape(icsMSG);
```

by

```
icsMSG="data:text/calendar;charset=utf8," + encodeURIComponent(icsMSG);
```

now, the stream is utf8 and work fine to post ics ical by this way.

Problem solved!